# How to i move my project to github

Tags: git, github

I have a new spring maven project that I would like to upload to github so others can share it and update it.

I made a repo on github and I have my project all coded. but I dont know the commands I have to run on my mac to get my code into the repo on github

Answer (score 2):

Download SourceTree. It's the bomb.

Just do a `git clone YourRepoName` on the command line.

(or if u have a specific branch `git clone YourRepoName -b YourBranchName`)

Then just drag the cloned directory File from the finder window into sourceTree. It will recognize it's a git repo. Then just drop in your current project into the directory and commit it up. Then make sure you do a push and your good to go.

Let me know if you have trouble.

Comment: no want to use just the git client. so do I goto the folder with the code and just do a git clone?

Comment: but what if it already contains a .git directory with its own contents